# Has anyone successfully resized a filesystem on Centos 7.x to over 16TB

Tags: linux, storage

I have a Centos 6.5 server connected to a storage array. It has a 16TB volume mounted from the array. If I resize the volume to 45TB on the array, I cannot expand the filesystem to use that space. Apparently Centos 7.x is certified for filesystems up to 50TB in size. Has anyone successfully resized an existing filesystem on 7.x to over 16TB?

```
[root@init105-12 hariharan]# lsblk /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101f
NAME                                     MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101f (dm-2) 253:2    0  45T  0 mpath
[root@init105-12 hariharan]#
[root@init105-12 hariharan]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/3624a93708a6e42d13a7d45ae0001101f
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits
```

Comment: Likely it's an ext3 filesystem or an ext4 converted longer ago from ext3. Use XFS.

Comment: It's an existing ext3 or ext4 production filesystem. So xfs is not an option, unless I'm missing something you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

The limit of ext4 is 16 TiB so you just can't
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1532

If it is a production env you have work to do...

Try to build the same server on a test environment with an XFS filesystem

Comment: Incorrect. That's only for <= RHEL 6.x (and even then 16TiB is the certified limit - versions >= RHEL 5.6 support up to 1EiB). This info is there in the link you posted. RHEL 7.x is certified for ext4 up to 50TiB.

Comment: You aren't on RHEL7 you are on RHEL6.  Your options are to upgrade to RHEL (CentOS) 7  or migrate to XFS. Consider XFS as it has been tested longer at the larger size.

Answer (score 2):

BACKGROUND: When this question comes up, there's often a lot of confusion about 64-bit OSes or people saying "64-bit filesystem". What we are talking about is the inode table in ext4 filesystems. The default block size in ext4 is 4k and the blocks are addressed with a 32-bit inode table which means that the filesystem has a limit of 2^32 * 4k addressable bytes which is 16TiB. For a long time now, the ext4 support in the Linux kernel has supported a 64-bit inode table (for a maximum of 1EiB using 4k blocks) however the e2fs tools that ship with CentOS 6 and 7 do not support this feature. If "RedHat certified" testing is meaningful to you, than the 64-bit inode table is not supported but the question was asked for CentOS so let's keep going.

DISCLAIMERS: I have enabled 64-bit inode tables for ext4 filesystems greater than 16TiB on CentOS 6 and 7 as well as older Ubuntus by updating the e2fs tools so I can tell you this does work but OF COURSE you should back up your data before trying this. This process involves compiling OS level tools so it is not for the faint of heart. Furthermore, I have read that GRUB does not support 64-bit inode tables so do not do this to your boot partition (or root filesystem if you keep /boot there but that is not how CentOS 6 or 7 installs itself). You have been warned.

Download e2fsprogs version 1.43.9 and build it. There are newer versions available but this version builds fine on both CentOS 6 and 7 and supports all the features we need whereas the newer code uses features unsupported by the version of gcc that ships with CentOS 6. Double note, this process requires gcc so if you don't want a compiler installed on a production server I recommend building on another box with the same Linux distro and then moving the built tools to your production environment. To begin, use the following commands:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs-1.43.9.tar.gz
tar zxvf e2fsprogs-1.43.9.tar.gz
cd e2fsprogs-1.43.9
./configure
make
```

At this point, you can run "make install" as root (NOTE the previous commands should NOT have been run as root/sudo) if you are on the system with the partition you want to expand. That will replace the existing e2fs tools on your system. If you don't want to do that, you can simply run the binaries you just built which I will assume you are doing going forward. Let's start by examining the filesystem in question. I will use `/dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data` in my example commands but you may have `/dev/sdb1` or something like that as your target. This command and all of the following commands that operate on the filesystem require root permission to run.

```
./misc/tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data | grep "features"
```

This command will list all the enabled filesystem features. If it has "64bit" on the list, then you are already done and I don't know why you're reading this! Before you can continue, you likely need to do an e2fsck and unmount the filesystem. Hopefully you know how to unmount the file system (which does require all file handles to files in the file system be closed). To do the fsck, the command is:

```
./e2fsck/e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data
```

This may take a while if the filesystem is already quite large. Next, we can (finally) upgrade the inode table to 64-bit:

```
./resize/resize2fs -b /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data
```

Note that this does not resize the file system. You must run the command again without the -b switch to do the actual resize. Running the resize command without specifying a size will automatically use all available space which is normally what you want to do:

```
./resize/resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data
```

You can now mount the drive and enjoy the extra space! You can also run `tune2fs` again to check that the filesystem features list shows that sweet "64bit" now.

Final tip: if you do want to build these tools on one box and then move them to your production server, the easiest way to do that is by doing this (not as root):

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
tar zcvf e2fsprogs.tar.gz $HOME/local
```

And then copy the e2fsprogs.tar.gz to your production server. You'll find the binaries that were built in the sbin folder. With them on your production server, you can run them directly from wherever you extracted them or you can move the folders extracted into local to /usr (as root) to replace the e2fs tools that shipped with your OS.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up migrating to xfs. With xfs resizing is a breeze.

Comment: Nothing wrong with choosing XFS. My main problem with XFS is that you cannot shrink the filesystem (unless you dump and restore it). This comes up for me more frequently than you'd imagine!

Answer (score 0):

Should have made it clear that the question is about ext4 on 64-bit linux.

Whether you can consider resizing depends on:

- Current size, new size, whether FS has 64bit feature enabled
- If both current and new size are <= 16TB then it should be safe
- If new size is > 16TB and FS already has 64bit feature enabled, it
  should be safe
- If new size is > 16TB and FS does not have 64bit feature, you first
  need to enable 64bit. You have to run *resize2fs -b* to enable it
  followed by the actual resize. Even the resize2fs that comes with RHEL 7.x
  does not accept the -b option. You have to build the ext4 tools from
  sources for that. Also -b is apparently not supported by Red Hat. So
  it does not look safe to resize in this case.